# Executable running on either .NET Framework 3.5 or 4.0

Tags: c#, .net

We have various versions of our base application out in the field:

- Version 1.0 comes bundled with .NET Framework 3.5
- Version 2.0 comes bundled with .NET Framework 4.0

We distribute updates via an installer which embeds a .NET executable in them.  The PC that this installer runs on may have the following combinations of our base application:

- Both Version 1.0 and Version 2.0 (.NET 3.5 / .NET 4.0)
- Version 1.0 only (.NET 3.5 only)
- Version 2.0 only (.NET 4.0 only)

I need to ensure that the .NET executable embedded in the installer will run reliably.

The approaches I have found suggest adding the following to the `app.config` file:

```
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
</startup>
```

A few questions:

1. Will this mean that it will use .NET Framework 4.0 if it is present, otherwise resorting to .NET Framework 3.5 (or any previous frameworks that use the `2.0.50727` CLR)?  IOW, are these tags ordered by priority?
2. Does the version of the .NET Framework on the build machine have any run-time effect on the application, or does the hardcoding of the versions in the `app.config` file always take priority?
3. What happens if I added code which relied upon a feature specific to .NET 4.0?  Would including the `2.0.50727` version in the `app.config` (as shown above) result in a compile-time error, or a run-time error (only if .NET 4.0 wasn't installed)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Yes, they're ordered by priority. It's easiest to try that with a simple console app:

   ```
   using System;

   class Test
   {
       static void Main()
       {
           Console.WriteLine(Environment.Version);
       }
   }
   ```

   Compile that with .NET 3.5, then run it with your current configuration, and it'll show 4.0 - then switch the lines and it'll show 2.0. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w519wzk.aspx) for more details.
2. The version of the framework that you've *targeted* your app at is the important thing. If your config specifies that you support .NET 2, but you've targeted .NET 4, the application won't start.
3. You won't have relied on a feature specific to .NET 4 without targeting .NET 4, in which case it won't run on .NET 2.

Point 3 isn't *strictly* accurate, in that there are things you can do which *will* differ based on which version of .NET is running. For example, change the app to:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        object o = new List<string>();
        Console.WriteLine(o is IEnumerable<object>);
    }
}
```

When running with .NET 2 that will print False (because `IEnumerable<T>` was invariant in .NET 2) but when running with .NET 4 it will print True because of generic covariance.

Comment: Currently, the "Target Framework" in the project settings is set to .NET 3.5.  Yet even without .NET 3.5 framework installed, my application runs successfully with the `app.config` settings in my question.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Apologies, I just read that MSDN article and it looks like the behaviour I mentioned in the above comment would be expected (I'm assuming "built against" in that article means the "Target Framework" setting of the project?).

Comment: Something is not making sense here - I am using VS2010, have set the "Target framework" in my project to 3.5, and have uninstalled .NET Framework 3.5.  With my `app.config` as shown above, the first console app you posted will always output `2.0.50727.4952` regardless of the order of the `supportedRuntime` tags.  I have confirmed that the only version of .NET Framework that I have installed is 4.0.

Comment: @JonSkeet, can you explain for us Jon, if I put a Lambda statement in the console app above the `Environment.Version' it still prints .Net v2. How can this be when Linq and Lambda's were introduced with .Net 3.0? (Edit targeting .Net 3.5)

Comment: After further investigation, I think the strange behaviour I mentioned in my comments above is caused by the .NET Framework 3.5 being a core component of Windows 7 which I am using.  It seems that it can't really be uninstalled, per-se.

Comment: However, if I deploy my .NET 3.5 app on a PC that ONLY has 4.0 installed, it will only work if I also copy a `.config` file to the target PC with 4.0 specified as a supported runtime.  This seems to contradict the MSDN page which says the following: "If the version of the .NET Framework that the application was built against is not present and a configuration file does not specify a version in a <supportedRuntime> Element, the application runs on the latest version of the .NET Framework that is present on the computer."

Comment: @JeremyThompson: Lambda expressions are a *source code* thing - you can still convert them to delegates (but not expression trees) in .NET 2, so long as you *build* with the C# 3 compiler. Ditto anonymous types, implicit variable declarations etc.

Comment: @LeopardSkinPillBoxHat: I don't know, I'm afraid. I would have expected that to work, as you say.

Comment: @JonSkeet - That's okay, thanks for your great answer anyway.